# Materialize framework: responsive logo in navbar

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I'm creating a website in materialize framework. I have a problem with logo in navbar. So my logo is very big (6202x3800 px) and I don't have any other version. I want to put this logo in navbar but it always exceeds the frame of `nav-wrapper`. I tried to add class `responsive-img` but it didn't work at all.

Here is my code:

```css
#allcontent {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2%;
}
body {
  background: #d26335;
}
nav {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="allcontent">
  <div class="navbar-default" id="navbar">
    <nav class="white">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="index.html" class="brand-logo left"><img class="responsive-img" id="logo" src="<!-- my image -->"/></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="sass.html"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
          </li>
          <li>colors</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All you have to do is control the size of the image with CSS to whatever dimensions you want:

```
.navbar-material .nav-wrapper .brand-logo img {
    height: 64px;
}
```

Or use a image editor to resize the image to something more reasonable for a logo to start with. See [Photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/), [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or [Sketch](http://www.sketchapp.com/#2) to name a few.

(*And definitely compress images; if you're not using a build system to do this there's always something like [TINYpng](https://tinypng.com/))

**See working example Snippet.**

(**note all classes used are default [MaterialCSS](http://materializecss.com/) minus the `.navbar-material` class and it looks like you're mixing Bootstrap3 classes with MaterialCSS classes)

```js
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

```css
body {
  background: #d26335;
}
nav.navbar-material {
  background: #d26335;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-material .nav-wrapper {
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
}
.navbar-material .nav-wrapper > ul > li > a {
  color: black;
}
.navbar-material .nav-wrapper .brand-logo img {
  height: 64px;
}
.navbar-material .nav-wrapper .button-collapse i {
  color: black;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar-material .nav-wrapper .brand-logo img {
    height: 56px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar-material">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/6202x3800/FF001E/fff">
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It's workinkg :D Thanks a lot and I appreciate that. ;)

Comment: No problem and don't forget to mark your question as answered if the solution worked so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Great answer! But I don't understand why you should specify the size for the logo for @media (max-width: 600px). Isn't this the job of materilizecss, is this a materilizecss?

Comment: This question relates to [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html). The height of the nav changes from 64px to 56px @ under 600px by default if check the computed output in DevTools. So as far as I know the navbar (specifically the class *brand-logo*) does not account for images, only text, so that's why dimensions had to be applied to the image especially given that the image in the question is 6202x3800 px. Hope that helps.